# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'emp_info'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to learn an Inheritance concept for the class. I am getting an error for a class attribute. An Error is coming on this line --> 
print(parent.emp_info())

My Python script is:

```
class Person:
def __init__(self, fname, lname):
    self.fname = fname
    self.lname = lname
    self.email = fname+lname+'@company.com'

def emp_info(self):
    return self.email


class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self, fname, lname, ID, Cell_No):
        Person.__init__(self, fname, lname)
        self.ID = ID
        self.Cell_No = Cell_No

    def get_emp_details(self):
        return self.emp_info() + ' ' + self.ID + ' ' + self.Cell_No


parent = ('Sam', 'Robinson')
child = ('Ronny', 'Joice', '123', '27389476231')

print(parent.emp_info())
parent(child.get_emp_details())
```

Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: You aren’t actually creating class instances, just tuples.

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you that `child` is a tuple, because that's what `('Ronny', 'Joice', '123', '27389476231')` is. You want an `Employee`.

To instantiate (i.e. make an instance of) a class, you need to use the class name:

```
child = Employee('Ronny', 'Joice', '123', '27389476231')
```